# Setting properties for combobox in the form.open event Access 2019

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have the following piece of code located in the open event of a form.

```
    If GetUserName = "Bob" Or GetUserName = "Ned" Then
        Me.cbo_Position2.LimitToList = False
        Me.cbo_Position2.AllowValueListEdits = True
        Me.cbo_Position2.ListItemsEditForm = frm_MasterDropDown_lookup
    End If
```

I'm using this code to set who can edit a combo box list.  The combo box is bound to a field on the form and the combobox info  is in a separate lookup table.  What I want to know is whether or not these properties can be set as the form opens.

When I run this code, it executes with no errors but the properties do not change.  I also tried doing 'Me.Refresh' at the end but that did not help.  My assumption at this time is that they can't be "set on the fly" so to speak.  If not, I was wondering if there is something I'm missing to get this to work.

TIA,
Tim

Comment: Try moving that code to the _Load_ event, or even the _OnCurrent_ event.

Comment: Also probably need to set ListItemsEditForm property to a string: `="frm_MasterDropDown_lookup"` - assuming that is actual name of form and not a VBA variable.

Comment: Tested and I get "Cannot set at this time" error in both Open and Load events. Odd and unexpected. Think I would not change these properties and just use NotInList event with If Then condition.

Answer (score 0):

From Access help:

1.If you set the combo box's BoundColumn property to any column other than the first visible column (or if you set BoundColumn to 0), the LimitToList property is automatically set to Yes.

2.When the LimitToList property of a bound (bound control: A control used on a form, report, or data access page to display or modify data from a table, query, or SQL statement. The control's ControlSource property stores the field name to which the control is bound.) combo box is set to No, you can enter a value in the combo box that isn't included in the list. Microsoft Access stores the new value in the form's underlying table (table: A database object that stores data in records (rows) and fields (columns). The data is usually about a particular category of things, such as employees or orders.) or query (query: A question about the data stored in your tables, or a request to perform an action on the data. A query can bring together data from multiple tables to serve as the source of data for a form or report.) (in the field specified in the combo box's ControlSource property), not the table or query set for the combo box by the RowSource property. To have newly entered values appear in the combo box, you must add the new value to the table or query set in the RowSource property by using a macro or Visual Basic event procedure (event procedure: A procedure that is automatically executed in response to an event initiated by the user or program code, or that is triggered by the system.) that runs when the NotInList event occurs.

Example for setting property:

Forms("Order Entry").Controls("States").LimitToList = False